# how to correctly postMessage into an iframe that has sandbox attribute enabled

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cors

See below sample code

- If I comment out the "sandbox" attribute line, everything run just fine.
- if I uncomment the "sandbox" attribute line, in chrome open developer console, we will see error "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.bing.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')."

any idea how to solve this problem?

```
const iframeElement = document.createElement("iframe");
iframeElement.src = "https://www.bing.com"
//iframeElement.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts");
iframeElement.onload = (e) => {
  iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "https://www.bing.com");
};

const containerElement = document.getElementById("place-holder-for-iframe");
containerElement.appendChild(iframeElement);
```

You can try it out with this jsbin link
http://jsbin.com/gafobulife/edit?js,output

- open js bin link in chrome
- open chrome developer tool --> go to Console tab
- uncomment the sandbox line
- click "run with js" from jsbin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't set `allow-same-origin` in the sandbox attribute, the content is treated as if it is from a unique origin: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes, and https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/.

Confusingly, `allow-same-origin` doesn't mean that the iframe will be able to access its parent, as if they were of the same origin (unless they are of the same origin), but it means that it will be able to treated as if it's from its normal origin (in this case, `https://www.bing.com`).

So you can either change:

```
iframeElement.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts")'
```

to

```
iframeElement.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin");
```

or if you don't want your iframe to maintain its origin, change:

```
iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "https://www.bing.com");
```

to

```
iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "*");
```

For me, there are additional errors if I don't use `allow-same-origin`, most likely from how `bing.com` is configured.

Comment: Just keep in mind that "allow-scripts" and "allow-same-origin" combined produce a security risk, and the sandbox can be removed.

Comment: iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "*"); worked for me perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @kintsukuroi, just to add, I think it's only a security risk if the url for the iframe is the same origin as its parent. It shouldn't be able to access its own sandbox attribute if it is of a different origin. See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox "Setting both the allow-scripts and allow-same-origin keywords together when the embedded page has the same origin as the page containing the iframe allows the embedded page to simply remove the sandbox attribute and then reload itself, effectively breaking out of the sandbox altogether."